# Brown-forsythe test showing statistical differences and posthoc analysis Gameshowell not

Tags: hypothesis-testing, post-hoc

I have a data sample whose structure looks like the below:

```
Product | Week Nr. | Amount of Sales (USD)
```

When I perform the Brown–Forsythe test, I've got a p-value smaller than my alpha value.

```
p-value: 0.010
```

which proves that there's a statistically significant difference in sales in each week of the month (given a confidence interval of 95%).

So then, when I perform a Gameshowell posthoc analysis and I get the below results, which I don't see any statistically significant difference amongst the groups anymore.

```
A   B   mean(A)  mean(B)   T       df       pval       hedges
W1  W2  155.191  267.168  -2.435   139.151  0.072051  -0.397
W1  W3  155.191  193.014  -1.069   146.178  0.713175  -0.170
W1  W4  155.191  174.582  -0.540   150.557  0.900000  -0.085
W2  W3  267.168  193.014   1.689   133.430  0.330372   0.259
W2  W4  267.168  174.582   2.090   136.953  0.157914   0.317
W3  W4  193.014  174.582   0.555   179.983  0.900000   0.082
```

I was thinking that the Gameshowell analysis was the proper analysis after a Brown-Forsythe test. Am I missing something or am I analysing wrong the result?